# Error during OpenId "discovery" process

Tags: openid

I'm trying to implement yahoo openid for my application. But I get

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: s4s-att-invalid-value: Invalid attribute value for 'targetNamespace' in element 'schema'. Recorded reason: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: 'xri://$xrd*($v*2.0)' is not a valid value for 'anyURI'.

error during "discovery" process. 
I'm using "http://me.yahoo.com/rpriyanka_1011" as openid url for testing purpose.
Also I'm running my application from localhost and currently it doesn't have a domain name.
Could that be a reason for failure in 'discovery" process?

Comment: Lack of a domain name won't cause a failure. Try not including your username, I use `http://me.yahoo.com/` which seems to be working fine.
Also, double check you support international domain names. Are you using .net?

Comment: @Jon No, I'm using Apache Tubine framework, and the language used is java.

Comment: I used http://me.yahoo.com/ but still the same error occured.

Comment: It looks like a problem with validating the document. Also, it looks like you had a problem with using Google openId discovery a few months ago, did you (and how?) did you resolve that? It appears to be the same problem.

Comment: @Jon The problem has been resolved. Earlier I was using openid4java library and error occured for Google openid discovery. But when I replaced it with jopenid library, things started working fine for Google.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved. I am using jopenid library for Openid implementation. For Yahoo, I used following url for performing discovery and things are working fine now.
http://open.login.yahooapis.com/openid20/www.yahoo.com/xrds